# How to sort list by frequency and alphabetically?

Tags: python

```
def count_words(s, n):
    """Return the n most frequently occuring words in s."""

    # TODO: Count the number of occurences of each word in s

    words = s.split()

    counts = Counter(words)

    # TODO: Sort the occurences in descending order (alphabetically in case of ties)

    # TODO: Return the top n most frequent words.
    return counts.most_common(n)

print count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3)
```

The current output is:

```
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('bitter', 1)]
```

But the required one is:

```
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1)]
```

Since for the same frequency, it has to be sorted by alphabetically. So how to sort list 'counts' by frequency alphabetically?

Answer (score 4):

As indicated by the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

> **most_common([n])**
>
> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common() returns all elements in the counter. ***Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily***:

So the order of the ones listed with a count of 1 are not guaranteed in any particular order because the underlying structure is a `dict`.

If you want your results alphabetically, you'll need to do some more processing.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter() #counter generating code

print sorted(c.most_common(), key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0]))[:3]
```

This basically grabs all your results first via. [`.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), then [sorts them](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) by 2nd parameter (the word frequency) in descending order, then 1st parameter (the word) in ascending order. Finally taking the [slice](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) of the first 3 elements for your result.

**Edit:** I realized that I wasn't sorting properly, and [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is limited to only ascending order.

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: How to fix the sorting by using itemgetter?

Comment: You would have to sort it twice, to get your results using `itemgetter`. `sorted(sorted(c.most_common(), key=itemgetter[0]), key=itemgetter[1], reverse=True)[:3]`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by specifying a key function

```
>>> L = [('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('bitter', 1), ('betty', 1)]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1), ('bitter', 1)]
```

Since Python's sort is stable, another way is to sort alphabetically first and then a reversed sort by count

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(sorted(L), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1), ('bitter', 1)]
```

Comment: @RafaelC Apply this to the result of most_common without arguments. Slice off the first n elements.

Comment: @MadPhysicist lol now it makes sense :) I commented before edit.

Comment: Might be easier to do this with items instead of most_common

Answer (score 0):

First count all the words using the concept of a bucket, defined by a dictionary where the keys are the words and the values are the number of occurrences.

```
>>> bucket = {}
>>> for word in words:
...     if word in bucket:
...         bucket[word] += 1
...     else:
...         bucket[word] = 1
...
>>> bucket
{'betty': 1, 'bought': 1, 'a': 1, 'bit': 1, 'of': 1, 'butter': 2, 'but': 1, 'the': 1, 'was': 1, 'bitter': 1}
```

You can use the sorted function with no arguments to sort by key name.

```
>>> sorted(bucket)
['a', 'betty', 'bit', 'bitter', 'bought', 'but', 'butter', 'of', 'the', 'was']
```

Then to sort by value, from highest to lowest:

```
>>> sorted(bucket.items(), key=lambda kv_pair: kv_pair[1], reverse=True)
[('butter', 2), ('betty', 1), ('bought', 1), ('a', 1), ('bit', 1), ('of', 1), ('but', 1), ('the', 1), ('was', 1), ('bitter', 1)]
```

Comment: Aside from reinventing the wheel of itertools.Counter (which OP is already using), this solution has already been presented.